# how to decrease lower body fats,?

Tags: body-fat

I am 18 years old and 
My lower body is wider than my upper body .when i am dressed my shirt looks shorter than my pants and also my thighs are wider than my base.
My chest is 36 inches 
   ,stomach is 39 inches
   ,base is 41 inches
   And my thighs are of 42inches
   Please help me out I am in deep deep problem...
Thanks☺

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately losing fat in one area, "spot reduction" is not possible

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_reduction

http://breakingmuscle.com/strength-conditioning/spot-reduction-one-final-attempt-to-kill-the-myth

It'll have to be achieved from a combination of dieting and aerobic exercises to reduce overall body fat, good luck!